# How can I make a one-dimensional array into a two-dimensional array using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have data that looks like this:

```
>>>npfilled[:5]

array([('!', 0, 0, 3, 10, 0, 2, 4, 4), ('!"', 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0),
       ('"', 23, 13, 20, 32, 0, 0, 22, 9),
       ("'", 21, 8, 23, 12, 5, 10, 0, 7), ('(', 3, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0)], 
      dtype=[('token', '<U64'), ('mel_freq1', '<i2'), ('mel_freq0', '<i2'), ('mel_freq2', '<i2'), ('mel_freq3', '<i2'), ('aus_freq0', '<i2'), ('aus_freq1', '<i2'), ('aus_freq2', '<i2'), ('aus_freq3', '<i2')])

>>>npfilled.shape
(301,)
```

But I need it to be `(301,2)`, so that I can slice it and perform other analyses on it, which I currently can't really do. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In numpy terms, you're asking how to convert a structured array into a "normal" 2D array, where each item in the structure is along a new axis.

On a quick side note, for heterogeneous data such as this, `pandas` is probably more what you're looking for.

That having been said, here's a quick explanation:

---

First off, to slice columns from your current structured array, you'd do something like:

```
import numpy as np

# Your example data...
data = np.array([('!', 0, 0, 3, 10, 0, 2, 4, 4),
                 ('!"', 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                 ('"', 23, 13, 20, 32, 0, 0, 22, 9),
                 ("'", 21, 8, 23, 12, 5, 10, 0, 7),
                 ('(', 3, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0)],
        dtype=[('token', '<U64'), ('mel_freq1', '<i2'),
               ('mel_freq0', '<i2'), ('mel_freq2', '<i2'),
               ('mel_freq3', '<i2'), ('aus_freq0', '<i2'),
               ('aus_freq1', '<i2'), ('aus_freq2', '<i2'),
               ('aus_freq3', '<i2')])

# Print out two arbitrary columns.
print data[['token', 'aus_freq1']]
```

Which would give:

```
[(u'!', 2) (u'!"', 0) (u'"', 0) (u"'", 10) (u'(', 0)]
```

You may not really want to switch to a "normal" array if you have heterogeneous data.

However, if you did want to switch it over, you're probably thinking of something along the lines of:

```
array([[u'!', 0, 0, 3, 10, 0, 2, 4, 4],
       [u'!"', 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [u'"', 23, 13, 20, 32, 0, 0, 22, 9],
       [u"'", 21, 8, 23, 12, 5, 10, 0, 7],
       [u'(', 3, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)
```

### The short answer:

---

If you're not terribly concerned about memory usage, you can just do:

```
np.array(data.tolist(), dtype=object)
```

---

### The longer answer:

The line above gets what you want with very little fuss. However, there are two slight downsides to this approach.

1. An intermediate list is constructed, and
2. An object array is returned, which is much less memory efficient than the original structured array.

There's no way around the second problem. It's the reason structured arrays exist. Object arrays (arrays of pointers) are not as compact in memory as structured arrays, but they can hold any arbitrary object.

However, if just want to get the homogeneous portions of your original structured array, then you can do something similar to:

```
# Only the first column is text...
numeric_cols = list(data.dtype.names[1:])

# View the non-text parts as an array with the same dtype as the numeric cols:
data2d = data[numeric_cols].view('<i2')

# And reshape it into a 2D array:
data2d = data2d.reshape(-1, len(numeric_cols))
```

This yields:

```
In [10]: data2d
Out[10]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  3, 10,  0,  2,  4,  4],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [23, 13, 20, 32,  0,  0, 22,  9],
       [21,  8, 23, 12,  5, 10,  0,  7],
       [ 3,  2,  2,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=int16)
```

This approach is more verbose, but if you have a very large array, it will be much faster.